# Camel URIResolver resolving relative path on outside http server

Tags: java, xslt, apache-camel

I'm having trouble with Camel xslt transformation. I want to have server http which contains xsl files. Those files are included using direct path created in my program like:
**xml:include href="http://serverName.com/files/file.xsl"/**
But then on the server, files should include another files but using relative paths. So it looks like 
**xml:include href="../directory/file.xsl"/**

I wrote my own URIResolver which ovverides method resolve
    @Override
    public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
        base = testBase;
        if (href == null || href.equals(""))
            throw new TransformerException();

```
    if (base == null || base.equals(""))
        return resolve(href);

    String uri = createUri(href, base);

    return resolve(uri);
}
```

but base parameter is always null. I read that this parameter is somehow connected to systemID but I don't know what to do with it. I only create the first main xsl file and then everything else is processed by Camel Transformer. What is more this transformer is singletone in my application so I can't load different URIResolver each time I start transformation. Therfore only option seems to be storing information about server address inside xsl file (preferably main file which has direct paths to server). I tried to do this with  but all I got is URIResolver getting something like @baseDir/directory/file.xml in href parameter and base is still null.

So does anyone have an idea how to do this? Preferably with Camel but if it proves itself to be impossible maybe you have suggestions about another framework?

Thanks for all responses in advance
Lukasz

Comment: So, your plan is to return different URIs depending on the environment?

Comment: yes, depending on configuration we should use different server. All servers have the same file directory structure so only address of server should be changed